# Client Mongoose C app to query LAN DNS?

Tags: c, networking, dns, host, lan

I'm experimenting with Cesanta's [Mongoose](https://docs.cesanta.com/mongoose/master/) server/"client" networking library in C. This is in Windows 7 x64 using [Pelle's C](http://smorgasbordet.com/pellesc/). I'm trying to make a LAN-capable text messaging app on port 90 as two dialog-as-main executables (server and client) to support 20 connections to the server. FWIW, I'm using a fast timer to call `mg_mgr_poll(&mgr, 0)` which retains UI responsiveness and uses very little CPU.

Cesanta gives good examples of server communication setup and that works flawlessly.  I can also get a client to connect to the server, but the server's IP address must be used in `mg_connect()`.

Since the server's hostname is public to the LAN, I was hoping to ask the LAN for this host's IP. I had this working in VB awhile ago:

```
Dim host As New IPHostEntry
host = Dns.GetHostEntry(hostName)
Return host.AddressList.GetValue(0)
```

However as the VB project got bigger, VB got stranger and much more difficult, so I migrated to good old C. (Perhaps it was falling back to a NetBIOS name query, dunno.) No, I'd rather not migrate again to C# or C++/VS.

The Cesanta [documentation](https://docs.cesanta.com/mongoose/master/#/c-api/dns.h/mg_send_dns_query.md/) on DNS resolution is quite vague. Code like `mg_connect(&mgr, "MyServerPC:90", ev_handler);` simply crashes, despite `mg_connect` stating it will try and resolve hostnames.

*Can* Mongoose resolve a local (LAN) hostname, and *how*? Or is this futile, and should everything be done manually in Winsock?

Answer (score 1):

i have the same issue as you.

First i think that the mg_connect should not crashes, only if you try to do something with the returned connection which is null.

Second, mongoose try to resolve the address using DNS from specific location at the registry and it's take the first address he can find.

The location is :`SYSTEM\\ControlSet001\\Services\\Tcpip\\Parameters\\Interfaces`
,check here in each of the interfaces.
i think there is a bug here (i am going to open an issues for it and also try to fix it and created a pull request).
Little update:
i have opend an issue and create a pull request about this issue.
https://github.com/cesanta/mongoose/issues/832
https://github.com/cesanta/mongoose/pull/833

Mongoose check each interface for the Value of NameServer and DhcpNameServer ,and return the first one (which is not empty) it can find but if it found an empty value for NameServer it doesn't check DhcpNameServer(and therefore miss the correct address) which will cause an error and direct the name resolving to a default server(i think it's google DNS -8.8.8.8).

You can fix this by going to the registry and adding the value of your DNS address to the registry key-NameServer

this is a comment from mongoose code:

> ```
>     /*
>      * See https://github.com/cesanta/mongoose/issues/176
>      * The value taken from the registry can be empty, a single
>      * IP address, or multiple IP addresses separated by comma.
>      * If it's empty, check the next interface.
>      * If it's multiple IP addresses, take the first one.
>      */
> ```